# A question on the proof of $\text{pf}(MAM^T) = \text{det}(M) \cdot \text{pf}(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

There is a step in the proof of pf($MAM^T$) = det($M$) pf($A$) 
for a skew symmetric matrix $A$
that I do not understand. The proof I can find basically says that 
$$\text{det}(MAM^T) = (\text{det} M)^2 \text{det}(A),$$ thus
$$\text{pf}(MAM^T)^2 = (\text{det} M)^2 (\text{pf} A)^2.$$ and by taking square root of both sides we obtain
$$\text{pf}(MAM^T) = \pm (\text{det} M) \text{pf} A.$$
Then the proof ends by substituting $M=I$ and concludes the sign must be positive.

My question is, isn't it possible that the sign can be sometimes positive and sometimes negative, hence substituting $M=I$ is not suffice to show that the sign is always positive?

Comment: pf? maybe I'm just tired, but no operator comes to mind with initials pf on it.

Comment: I mean the Pfaffian of the matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: if $\det A\ne 0$, $$f(M) := \frac {\operatorname{pf}(MAM^T)} {\operatorname{pf}A\cdot \det M}$$ is well-defined and continuous on $GL(n,\mathbb C)$.